# How to print a new line or automatically print new line when the text's length is over the windows size in Python?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame

I want to print to the new line when the text's length is over the width of the window or over the length I limited. "\n" isn't working here because I was using a function to shape the text message.

Sample:

```
input_message = "Hello, world!"
message = text_format(input_message, font, 90, yellow)

# Text Renderer
def text_format(message, textFont, textSize, textColor):
    newFont=pygame.font.Font(textFont, textSize)
    newText=newFont.render(message, 0, textColor)
    return newText
```

I expect input_message will print like:

"Hello, "

"world!" ("world!" is over windows width).

How to modify the text_format function to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS property `text-overflow`

The `text-overflow` property specifies how overflowed content that is not displayed should be signaled to the user. It can be clipped, display an ellipsis (...), or display a custom string.

```css
.container {
  white-space: normal; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">The text-overflow property specifies how overflowed content that is not displayed should be signaled to the user. It can be clipped, display an ellipsis (...), or display a custom string.</div>
```

Comment: `white-space: wrap` is not a valid value. Also your `text-overflow: clip` is doing nothing here...Its a default value

Comment: No. It is a CSS style